# Button inside link doesn't work in IE

Tags: html, css

I have sitewiode styling of buttons using the  html element. For buttons that submit forms this works well. However some buttons are just links. Therefore I use this syntax:

```
<a href="#"><button>Link Text</button></a>
```

This works perfectly in all browsers except IE, where the button clicks but nothing happens. The link isn't followed.

How can I get this to work in IE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't put the button inside the link. You can easily style the `<a>` to look just like the `<button>` with CSS.

Comment: Agree completely, just add a class to your links like link-button

Comment: The whole reason CSS exists is to allow you to separate style from content. If you're using `<button>` just because your CSS style is attached to `button { ... }`, you're coupling style with content.

Comment: Maybe so, but in this case it's redundant to have a button inside an anchor anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post more code?  As it stands, a `<button>` element inside a link element isn't a proper way to do this.  Stick to semantics.  You should just style the `<a>` element using CSS.  If you really want to stick to using that combination, IE requires you to use `type="button"`.  So `<button type="button"></button>`

Answer (score -2):

This is my issue also. Using code:

```
<a href="table_of_contents.html" title="Table of Contents"> 
    <button> <b>Contents</b> </button> 
</a>
```

It works for Firefox and Safari; but fails for Explorer and Opera.
Tried answer from Michel:

**Contents**

No change: Firefox and Safari OK; Explorer and Opera NG.

I have changed to the following code, which works for all four browsers.

```
<form action="table_of_contents.html"> 
    <input value="Contents" title="Table of Contents" 
        style="font-weight: bold" type="submit"> 
</form>
```

PS: This does NOT work for `type="button"`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is a terrible approach. You created a form that doesn't serve any purpose other than acting as an <a> tag by submitting to your destination. You should just style the <a> tag you started off with.